# 2010 Odyssey 2 monolith location

Tags: 2010-odyssey-two

In 2010 Odyssey 2, is the monolith freely orbiting Jupiter along with Discovery? And not embedded in a jovian moon? (I am completely aware of the discrepancies between 2001 and 2010)

Comment: The Monolith freely orbiting Jupiter and Leonov crew try to investigate it. Later monolith goes down to Jupiter to create a star. Is that what you want to know or something else?

Comment: Plot could be found on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010:_Odyssey_Two or just read the book)

Comment: or watch the movie - overall it's a fairly decent adaptation

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi perhaps post your comment as an answer so as to have this question be answered... I would do it but I have little knowledge and could not answer from my own.

Answer (score 3):

The Monolith was found at the Lagrange point between Io and Jupiter, and was commonly called the Jupiter Monolith. Later it goes down to Jupiter to create a new star.

> 'It's still ten thousand kilometres away, up there **at the libration point**,  but when I look at it through the main telescope it
> seems close enough to touch.  Because it's so completely featureless,
> there's no indication of size, no way  the eye can judge it's really a
> couple of kilometres long. If it's solid, it  must weigh billions of
> tons.

> 'I see the nightside of Jupiter. There is a circular area, 3,250
> kilometres  in diameter, which is almost compietely covered with
> rectangular objects.'
> There was the briefest of pauses, before Hal flashed the number on the video display: 1,355,000 ± 1,000. They are identical in size and shape to the object you refer to as Big Brother... **So the damn thing's gone down to Jupiter - and multiplied**.

[image]

Plot could be found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010:_Odyssey_Two)

[Audiobook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkiMAfO0jpY)